# Multiple variables in jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like this

```
$(".class1 .class2").on('click', function(){
 //Do something        
});
```

I am trying to somehting like this using variables:

```
var1=".class1";
var2=".class2"

$(var1 var2).on('click', function(){
   //Do something        
});
```

I see `var1` and `var2` are set to right values, but everytime I try to use 2 variables as selector it fails. When I keep the click trigger unchanged and use `var1` or `var2` elsewhere in the code individually (just `var1` or `var2` but not in the same selector list) it works. Any tips?

I figure I use `var3` concatenate `var1` and `var2`, but I am trying to reduce another variable.

Comment: Variables are cheap. `var1 var2` is not a list, it is a syntax error.... and even if it were a list, that list would be an object. Perhaps what you don't want is to pollute the name space, in that case, just do the concatenation inline as [adeneo suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40115547/402022).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the space. Without it, it becomes `.class1.class2` which means the element has to have both classes, not get the descendant of the first one, etc.

```
var1 = ".class1";
var2 = ".class2";

$(var1 + ' ' + var2).on('click', function(){
   //Do something        
});
```

Another option would be `find()`

```
$(var1).find(var2).on(...
```

Just doing `$(var1 var2)` would be the same as `var fail = var1 var2;` it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to use jQuery objects as your variables. This would avoid having to declare a third variable, which is pretty trivial to do, but if you really want to, there is a way.

This is assuming you are trying to apply the function to any element that has either class, which is not what your existing code example shows (`$(".class1 .class2").on`) , but to me it seems like this is what you are actually asking for.

```js
var var1 = $('.clickable');
var var2 = $('.anotherClass');

var1.add(var2).on('click', function() {
  console.log('button clicked!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clickable">Click 1</button>
<button class="anotherClass">Click 2</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sample code has a JavaScript syntax error (there should be a plus sign between var1 and var2, if you intend to concatenate them).  However, this would produce a selector ".class1.class2" which is not what you're looking for - this would find an element that has *both* classes, rather than elements that have either class1 or class2.

So, firstly, you need a plus sign to fix your syntax error. But then you'll need a *comma* between your class names to select the correct elements.

```
var1=".class1";
var2=".class2"

// Select ".class1,.class2" (either class1 or class2)
$(var1 + ',' + var2).on('click', function(){
   //Do something        
});
```

Comment: Why should there be a comma, where there once was a space ?

Comment: Good point... I've re-read it a few times now, and I still can't tell he *intended* the space to begin with. He never clearly says he wants a descendant element and I somehow read that he wants either class1 or class2.  Perhaps I'm wrong. I'll leave my answer as is, just in case, since you've already supplied the correct answer if he wanted the space.